# Android layout folders for different screen sizes

Tags: android, layout, screen, screen-size

I have an app that I need to ensure different devices are pulling from different layout folders. I need a nexus 5 (1920 x 1080) to pull from a different folder than a Note 4 (2560 x 1440).

Currently, no matter what combination of folder names, they both pull from the same folder.

I have tried:

```
layout-xxhdpi & layout-xxxhdpi
```

(they both pull from xxhdpi)

```
layout-sw320dp & layout-xxhdpi
```

(they both pull from layout-sw320dp

```
layout-large & layout-xlarge
```

(they both pull from layout-large)

What would be the proper layout folder convention for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this seems to be the only arrangement that worked for me...

`layout` (Nexus 4 & 5)

`layout-sw440dp-port` (Note 4, Nexus 6)

`layout-sw720dp-port` (Samsung 10" tablet)

(It I take off the "port" it doesn't work...) ;-)

Thanx for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to add the following folders:

- layout-sw320dp (xhdpi devices)
- layout-sw340dp (xxhdpi devices)
- layout-sw380dp (xxxhdpi devices)

you must add folders only if you really need another whole layout in different devices. Other than that , use only default layout folder with proper layout structure and extract dimensions on different density folders.

Comment: What will be the folder name for hdpi devices

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google device metrics](https://design.google.com/devices/), `Note 4` and `Nexus 5` both have `xxhdpi` density, but their widths and heights are different, so you should try playing with the `smallestWidth` qualifier. For example with this combination should work: `layout-sw360dp & layout-sw480dp` (You can read more about qualifiers [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html))

Answer (score -1):

This is the structure:

```
    res/layout
    res/layout-large
    res/layout-xlarge
    res/layout-sw600dp
    res/layout-sw720dp
    res/layout-sw800dp
```